# How can I run a jar from a fresh lein app without using uberjar?

Tags: jar, clojure, leiningen

I'm finding that a fresh app from lein can be run as an uberjar but not as a jar. Is it supposed to work this way, or is something wrong with my setup?

```
$ lein new app feedme
$ cd feedme
```

Lein uberjar works just fine:

```
$ lein uberjar
Compiling feedme.core
Created .../feedme/target/uberjar+uberjar/feedme-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created .../feedme/target/uberjar/feedme-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

$ java -jar target/uberjar/feedme-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
Hello, World!
```

Lein jar fails:

```
$ lein jar
Warning: The Main-Class specified does not exist within the jar. It may not be executable as expected. A gen-class directive may be missing in the namespace which contains the main method.
Created .../feedme/target/feedme-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
$ java -jar target/feedme-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class feedme.core
```

There's a :gen-class directive in the ns section of core.clj, so I'm not sure what the problem is:

```
$ cat src/feedme/core.clj 
(ns feedme.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lein jar only wraps up your own code in a jar, such that it could be used by another project for example. It does not include any of your dependencies (which will be declared in your `pom.xml`), including clojure itself. Without a valid class to run (eg. `clojure.main`), it can't run your code. And the next problem would be your require statements that refer to definitions in artifacts that are not on your classpath (unless some program loaded your `pom.xml` and knew how to fulfill those dependencies).

Answer (score 3):

Look inside any jar (they are just zip files) at its MANIFEST.MF file. That file will tell you the main class. So if you make sure MANIFEST.MF gets into your jar file it will be self-runnable. The jar file contains .class files and refers to other jar files - so it can make up its own classpath as long as the referred to jar files are accessible.

I've just looked inside a few jar files. `MANIFEST.MF` is in `META-INF`. Here's an example contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.7.0_76-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.cmts.client.applic.upgrader.UsersGUI
Date-Created: 15/07/2015 02:23 AM
Class-Path: ../lib/config-1.2.1.jar          
            ../lib/scala-library-2.11.5.jar                      
            ../lib/org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.RC2.jar       
            ../lib/org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.RC2.jar
```

This one was created by Ant. I don't know if lein does the same thing. But even if it does not there is no reason you can't have `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` being put into the jar. Then you will have a self-runnable jar file.

*later edit* - lein manifest example:

```
:manifest {"Class-Path" "../lib/clojure-1.8.0.jar"}
```

Comment: Ah, that's good to know. When you say "self-runnable" I guess that means you can run it like java -jar myapp.jar, not like ./myapp.jar.

Comment: Yes `java -jar myapp.jar` running the main class - that's what I meant by 'self-runnable'. Depending on your OS setup double clicking will do this. And all the classpath info doesn't need to be there as cp info, like the main class, is specified within the jar file itself.

Answer (score 2):

You get `Error: Could not find or load main class feedme.core` because the jar doesn't contain feedme/core.class file. If you run `jar -tf target/feedme-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` you'll see that it doesn't contain any .class file at all. `lein jar` doesn't compile sources by default. This is intended behaviour: Clojure compiles code on the fly unless AOT compilation is requested. In case of uberjar AOT compilation *is* requested in project.clj file via `{:uberjar {:aot :all}}` profile (you can do a small experiment by changing uberjar profile to an empty one `{:uberjar {}}`, then `lein uberjar && java -jar target/uberjar/feedme-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar` will result in exactly the same error).

You can run `lein with-profile uberjar jar` to compile your code. But if you run `java -jar target/uberjar+uberjar/feedme-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` you'll get another error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/IFn`. As pointed by noisesmith `lein jar` doesn't package any dependencies including Clojure itself. So you must explicitly specify Clojure in the classpath: `java -cp "$HOME/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar:target/uberjar+uberjar/feedme-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" feedme.core`. This will print Hello, World! (assuming you have Clojure 1.8 in your local Maven repo, you might need to fetch it first or change path/version).

Without compilation you can run jar generated with `lein jar` with: `java -cp "$HOME/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clojure-1.8.0.jar:target/feedme-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" clojure.main --main feedme.core` (again your path/version of Clojure's jar can be different).